# Eigen3 from Linux Mint 17.3 repo, SparseMatrix not named

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, eigen

I am trying to use Eigen3 in my project and I get this error when I try to build using CMake and make

```
/usr/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/src/KroneckerProduct/KroneckerTensorProduct.h:246:11: error: ‘SparseMatrix’ does not name a type
       typedef SparseMatrix<Scalar, 0, StorageIndex> ReturnType;
```

I am using Linux Mint 17.3. I have both the eigen2 and eigen3 libraries and I'm pretty sure the CMake is picking eigen3 (especially given the error message I posted above). I installed eigen3 using the command
`sudo apt-get install libeigen3-dev`.
When I run `apt-cache show libeigen3-dev` I get

```
Package: libeigen3-dev
Priority: extra
Section: universe/libdevel
Installed-Size: 5130
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian Science Maintainers <debian-science-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: all
Source: eigen3
Version: 3.3~beta1-2
Depends: pkg-config
Suggests: libeigen3-doc, libmrpt-dev
Filename: pool/universe/e/eigen3/libeigen3-dev_3.3~beta1-2_all.deb
Size: 662650
MD5sum: bad08ef7b1d166c5bc9903e510a9fb68
SHA1: ef35745fcd047f1a1f18834e02ccef1476d7407c
SHA256: 5c73d97dca2d950ce51bde451deed4b6508b2f6cca9b9b6563218591e029f17b
Description-en: lightweight C++ template library for linear algebra
 Eigen 3 is a lightweight C++ template library for vector and matrix math,
 a.k.a. linear algebra.
 .
 Unlike most other linear algebra libraries, Eigen 3 focuses on the simple
 mathematical needs of applications: games and other OpenGL apps, spreadsheets
 and other office apps, etc. Eigen 3 is dedicated to providing optimal speed
 with GCC. A lot of improvements since 2-nd version of Eigen.
Description-md5: 71025bd67be9e83075fd5a0e7ab822a2
Homepage: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
Supported: 9m
```

Here's a minimal code snippet:

```
#include <unsupported/Eigen/KroneckerProduct>
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

compiling with `g++ -std=c++11 -I /usr/local/include/eigen3 hello.cpp -o hello`
:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/KroneckerProduct:30:0,
                 from hello.cpp:4:
/usr/local/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/src/KroneckerProduct/KroneckerTensorProduct.h:246:11: error: ‘SparseMatrix’ does not name a type
   typedef SparseMatrix<Scalar, 0, StorageIndex> ReturnType;
```

Comment: how about the official version?

Comment: I tested the official version from the mercurial repo and I got the same error.

Comment: How about older version like 3.2.9. anyway it is `unsupported`

Comment: you may want to create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Tested 3.2.9 as well and same error.

Comment: at least you need to tell your compiler where to find `KroneckerProduct`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem can be solved with correct `inlcude`s. The first one defines `SparseMatrix` which corrects your first error message. The second one uses proper path which corrects your second error message.

```
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/KroneckerProduct>
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This still gives the same error that I originally listed. `SparseMatrix does not name a type...`

Comment: how do you comiple your code? what is the compile options?

Comment: `g++ -std=c++11 -I /usr/local/include/eigen3 hello.cpp -o hello`

Comment: @Steve.Q I cannot reproduce your problem with my code and your compile cmdline.

Comment: @Steve.Q in fact if I remove the first line in my code, I get the same error as yours.

Comment: You can't reproduce it but you're able to reproduce it when the <Eigen/Sparse> include is removed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117846/discussion-between-steve-q-and-kangshiyin).